# Django Compare Statement with field array

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a datepicker to my form and I am having a bit of trouble.  I had thought this bit of code would work but I can't seem to exclude the 'releasedate' tag within the field array.

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% if field.label_tag != "releasedate" %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
            {{ field.label_tag }}
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

My views.py:

```
class AlbumCreate(CreateView):
        model = music_models.Album
        fields = ['artist', 'album_title', 'genre', 'releasedate', 'notes', 'album_logo', 'rating']
```

Why am I wrong here?

Since I'm getting the discussion going, I suppose it doesn't hurt to ask a related question:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use
According to this I can specify things like this if using the ModelForm class

```
widgets = {
            'name': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}),
        }
```

Does the same apply when using any of the generic views?  If so, how do you apply it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the first question working by using the following:

```
{% if not "releasedate" in field.label_tag %}
```